# WYGWAM: All text showing as bold (though without strong tag)

Tags: wygwam

All text either pasted or typed into my WYGWAM fields shows as bold. Viewing source shows there are no strong tags.

The client is unable to tell which items are actually bolded because of this.

I've searched online extensively and can't find anyone else having this issue.

ExpressionEngine 2.7.2
Wygwam 3.2.1

Other add-ons installed: 
Pages 2.2 
Freeform Pro 4.1.3
Field Editor 1.0.4
Rich Text Editor 1.0.1

Comment: Showing bold only on the front-end or in the WYGWAM field on the edit page too?

Comment: If front-end please paste URL.

Comment: Also, do you have custom styles rendering in your settings?